# No WiFi adapter found - Looks like a kernel issue as kernel drivers and modules don't show up in the network controller

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, kernel, realtek

When I try to connect to WiFi on my Ubuntu 22.04.1 system (tried it on Fedora 36 as well), I get displayed the following error: "No WiFi Adaptor found". The most important issue I found is that the kernel drivers and modules don't show up for the network controller.

I tried running the following suggested commands:

`lshw -C network` returns:

`WARNING: you should run this program as super-user. *-network UNCLAIMED      description: Network controller product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. physical id: 0 bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0 version: 00 width: 64 bits clock: 33MHz capabilities: cap_list configuration: latency=0 resources: ioport:2000(size=256) memory:c0900000-c09fffff WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.`

`lsmod | grep rtw` returns nothing

`lspci -v | grep Wireless` returns:

`pcilib: Error reading /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:08.3/label: Operation not permitted`

`lspci -v` returns this information about the network controller:

`01:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device b852 Subsystem: Lenovo Device 4853 Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255, IOMMU group 12 I/O ports at 2000 [disabled] [size=256] Memory at c0900000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=1M] Capabilities: <access denied>`

I have a working Ubuntu setup in my other laptop and I noticed kernel information under the network controller but can't find the same here. Also, the I/O ports at 2000 are disabled here. Not sure what I should be doing from here on out. I tried searching up but couldn't find much information on device b852. I'm fairly new to Linux so please feel free to correct me.

Other information: The laptop I'm using is a Lenovo IdeaPad 5 14 (AMD Ryzen 5 6600)

Thanks in advance and any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT (Adding another command's output):

`Lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` returns:

`pcilib: Error reading /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:08.3/label: Operation not permitted 01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:b852] Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:4853] 02:00.0 SD Host controller [0805]: O2 Micro, Inc. SD/MMC Card Reader Controller [1217:8621] (rev 01) Subsystem: O2 Micro, Inc. SD/MMC Card Reader Controller [1217:0002]`

Comment: I am also new to the Ubuntu operating system. But I have done my fair sure of monkeying around with terminal. I will try my best to help. Whenever I get the message "permission denied", or "access denied", I just run the command: sudo -i, and log in as the root user. Try that.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Is there some reason you installed 20.04, an older version of Ubuntu for this quite new laptop? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Just tried that and it returns the same error

Comment: @chili555 Just added it to my post. Also my bad, I was wrong about my version, it's actually 22.04.1 which I believe is the latest.